# Could someone clarify what this session thing in PHP is doing?

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
if($err)
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
```

Three quick questions:

1. Why use a two-dimensional array here? Why not just say `$_SESSION['login-err']`?
2. How do session variables work? I've looked around and all I can seem to gather is that you can assign variables that are stored in the session, but are there any predefined variables?
3. In PHP can you have two dimensional and one dimensional arrays interchangeably? I'm used to needing a new variable if you want a different dimension of array.

Comment: 1. Is a matter of preference or semantic structuring. 2. Look into the manual http://php.net/sessions, and 3. Yes, arrays are actually dictionaries and sructurally free-form as they require no pre-assigned memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a design decision. You'll have to ask the developer who wrote it.
2. The $_SESSION array stores everything you throw at it. You use it like any other PHP array and it will be stored for following page loads. There are not any predefined session variables (try doing a [`var_dump($_SESSION)`](http://php.net/var_dump) if you want to check for yourself).
3. Yes, you can mix as you wish. "arrays" in PHP are actually hash maps, and each element may be any other PHP datastructure (including other arrays/hashmaps). So it's not *really* a multidimensional array, it's a hashmap storing other hashmaps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Well let's say you have a bunch of possible messages, not just a
   login error. Then you would want an array of messages to iterate
   through. Hence the msg array.
2. Session variables are useful for persistent data. You use
   `session_start();` at the beginning of each file that you want to
   access the session, and you can retrieve that data again. I don't
   know of any pre-defined variables, although I don't see why you'd
   really need them.
3. Can you clarify this question a little more?

Answer (score 2):

1. We don't know because we don't know the context or design of the original program.
2. PHP sessions are a great way to retain data from request-to-request. The `$_SESSION` variable retains its value for a given user until the session is closed or timed out. See all about PHP sessions here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
3. PHP arrays are very flexible and can add dimensions as necessary, as all that is being done to add new dimensions is placing one array inside an element of another. See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is a dictionary, not an array. While the syntax may look similar, you can insert as many things you want in a dictionary without having to redeclare it. `$_SESSION` has a another dictionary variable stored in its `'msg'` slot, so when you access `$_SESSION['msg']` it returns another dictionary, which you can then add a `'login-err'` slot in which points to `implode('<br />',$err);`. I guess whoever wrote the code wanted to organize all the messages together as one slot in the `$_SESSION` dictionary.

`$_SESSION` is a dictionary that is constant throughout all of your php files for the same session, allowing you to store and send information between php files. There are no predefined `$_SESSION` variables.